# How can I stop Finder from converting and loading videos to display in movie icons?

Tags: finder

I want movies to be displayed simply as movie icons.

But currently, and for the past few years, Finder loads (and if it is a strange format converts) the video and then displays an icon showing a still from the movie. That is very very annoying. How can I switch that off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn off the Finder's icon preview feature:

- Right click on the desktop > Choose 'Show View Options'
- Uncheck 'Show icon preview'

Comment: I just noticed that it was switched off on my Mac Pro (which still for some reasons starts converting Windows Media movies when opening a folder) and I guess it switched off on my MacBook too, until the Lion upgrade.